# Not able to receive location co-ordinates from this code?

Tags: java, android

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mycompany.talk" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >


    <activity
        android:name=".MainAppActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Login">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".UserRegistration">
</activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyC9QWvezlYxdZcmFLjUlRND44-g9Ardcp0"/>
</application>
<service android:name=".GeofenceTransitionsIntentService"/>
```

LocationReceiver.java

```
package com.mycompany.talk;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

/**
 * Created by joshua on 1/10/2016.
 */
public class LocationReceiver extends AppCompatActivity implements        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {
private LocationListener mLocationListener;
private LocationManager mLocationManager;
private static double mLatitudeText;
private static double mLongitudeText;
private int radius = 100;
private Location mLastLocation;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

I am referencing the android developer guide for this.

```
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
}
protected void onStart() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}

protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

private void setLat(double latitude) {
    this.mLatitudeText = latitude;
}


private void setLon(double longitude) {
    this.mLongitudeText = longitude;

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int x){

}
```

When I call the getters from MapFragment.java, my default coordinates are being used instead of the coordinates I should be receiving.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        setLat(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
        setLon(mLastLocation.getLongitude());
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult CR){

}

public static double getLat() {
    return mLatitudeText;
}

public static double getLon() {
    return mLongitudeText;
}
}
```

MapFragment.java

```
    package com.mycompany.talk.Fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.mycompany.talk.LocationReceiver;
import com.mycompany.talk.R;

public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{
SupportMapFragment mSupportMapFragment;

LocationReceiver LR;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mSupportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager sfm = getFragmentManager();
    mSupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    if(!mSupportMapFragment.isAdded())
    sfm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.map_frag,mSupportMapFragment).commit();

   else if(mSupportMapFragment.isAdded())
        sfm.beginTransaction().hide(mSupportMapFragment).commit();
    else
        sfm.beginTransaction().show(mSupportMapFragment).commit();

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    LR = new LocationReceiver();
    if (LR.getLat() != 0 && LR.getLon() != 0) {
        LatLng location = new LatLng(LR.getLat(), LR.getLon());
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("You"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));
    }
else{
        LatLng location = new LatLng(32.689576, -117.115744);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("You"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will not receive location until you request location updates.
You could set request values accordingly to save battery life.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...
   createLocationRequest();
}

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    ...
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
        mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}
```